# "Бабушка-официантка", "бабушка-кассир" - через дефис верно?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

> А зимой тут топят камин. И… выходишь из уютного английского домика, со
>   скрипучими полами, внимательными **бабушками-официантками** и рассеянной
>   **бабушкой-кассиром**, распахиваешь дверь – и ты в вечном водовороте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Написание через дефис, других вариантов просто нет.** Раньше  можно было ***старик (старый) сторож*** написать раздельно, а в правилах Лопатина это тоже дефисное написание: ***старик-отец, красавица-дочка***.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66#pp66